# Ruby ThreadsWait timeout

Tags: ruby, multithreading, timeout, thwait

I have the following code to block until all threads have finished ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/mahemoff/ae386626923a1015a387)):

```
ThreadsWait.all_waits(*threads)
```

What's the simplest way to set a timeout here, ie kill any threads if they are still running after e.g. 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thread#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Thread.html#method-i-join) accepts an argument after which it will time out. Try this, for example:

```
5.times.map do |i|
  Thread.new do
    1_000_000_000.times { |i| i } # takes more than a second
    puts "Finished" # will never print
  end
end.each { |t| t.join(1) } # times out after a second

p 'stuff I want to execute after finishing the threads' # will print
```

If you have some things you want to execute before joining, you can do:

```
5.times.map do |i|
  Thread.new do
    1_000_000_000.times { |i| i } # takes more than a second
    puts "Finished" # will never print
  end
end.each do |thread|
  puts 'Stuff I want to do before join' # Will print, multiple times
  thread.join(1)
end
```